# move oracle datafile in rac

Tags: oracle10g

We have a rac database system.
I add a new datafile but I did not choose Oracle Managed File from toad, unfortunately :(

So as I understand now, it created datafile in one node. So any session which connects to other node can not find the datafile and gives error message. So how can I move datafile to RAC shared area and change type of datafile to OMF?

Answer (score 0):

your problem has nothing to do with oracle managed files. Your problem - to me - looks like a lack of a skilled dba.
All you need to do is take the file or tablespace offline. Next transfer the file[s] to a shared device and rename the file to the newfile. From that point on all instances should be able to see the file[s]. How you should transfer the file[s] depends on how your storage is used. If it is on a cluster file system, you can copy the file any way you want to. If you are on raw devices, you need to have a raw device for every datafile and need something like dd to copy the data. If you are on ASM, use rman to do the transfer.

all the best,
Ronald
http://ronr.blogspot.com